# Neural network inputs

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I don't really know how to word this question so bear with me..

Let's say I am developing a neural network for rating each runner in an athletics race. I give the neural network information regarding the runner, eg. win%, days since last run etc. etc.

My question is - in this case where the neural network is rating runners, can I give the network an input like the race weather ? e.g. I give the network 1.00 for hot, 2.00 for cold, 3.00 for OK .. ?

The reason I am asking this question: The greater the output of the neural network, the better the runner. So, this means that the higher the win % input, the bigger the rating. If I give the neural network inputs whereby the greater the value doesn't necessarily mean the better the runner, will the network be able to understand and use/interpret this input?

Please let me know if the question doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neural nets can correctly model irrelevant inputs (by assigning them low weights) and inputs that are inversely related to the desired output (by assigning negative weights). Neural nets do better with inputs that are continuously-varying, so your example of `1.00 for hot, 2.00 for cold, 3.00 for OK ..` is not ideal: better would be `0.00 for hot, 1.00 for OK, 2.00 for cool`.

In situations such as your country code where there is no real continuous relationship, the best encoding (from a convergence standpoint) is to use a set of boolean attributes (`isArgentina, isAustralia, ..., isZambia`). Even without that, though, a neural net ought to be able to model an input of discrete values (i.e., *if* countries were relevant and if you encoded them as numbers, *eventually* a neural net should be able to converge on `87 (Kenya) is correlated with high performance`). In such a situation, it might take more hidden nodes or a longer training period.

The whole *point* of neural nets is to use them in situations where simple statistical analysis is difficult, so I disagree with the other answer that says that you should pre-judge your data.

Comment: Always, always, always(!!) start with some simple exploratory data analysis (such as a simple plot). Even if you *think* that your data is so complex, advanced, obfuscated (whatever really) it most often turns out that there are some really simple properties to be observed. Also, the human eye (or brain if you will) is still unsurpassed when it comes to pattern analysis and recognition. A 10 line script to plot the data and a 10 minute glance may be worth several thousands line of code (for example, doing outlier detection). Always do EDA!!

Comment: @Niclas It's true that basic analysis is a good idea, like using a spellchecker. But any problem that falls to 10 minutes of analysis is, by definition, not a problem that requires advanced techniques. In the 22 years since I first wrote neural net code, I've *never* been asked to apply them to trivially separated data.

Comment: @Larry OBrien, many thanks for the clear and informative answer.

Comment: @Larry OBrien, to each his own I guess :) I like "looking" at data whenever possible and I'm a strong believer of that approach. But of course you are completely right in that for some data-set it's simply no use.. But at least you discover that quickly, instead of missing something simple about the data-set for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

What a neural network does is map relations between inputs and outputs. This means that you have to have some kind of objective for your neural network. Examples of such objectives could be "to predict the winner", "to predict how fast each runner will be" or to "predict the complete results from a race". Which of those examples that are plausible for you to attempt depends, of course, on what data you have available.

If you have a large dataset (say e.g. a few hundred races for each runner) where the resulting time and all predictory variables (including weather) are recorded and you establish that there *is* a relationship between weather and an individual runners performance a neural network would very well be able to map such a relationship, even if it is a different relationship for each individual runner.

Example of good weather variables to record could be sun intensity (W/m2), head wind (m/s) and temperature (deg C). Then each runners performance could be modeled using these variables and then the neural network could be used to predict a runners performance (observe that this approach would require one neural network per runner).

Comment: Let's say for example i am looking at a horse race, and I would like to rate each horse as described above. I would like to give the neural network the country in which the horse was bred. I would then convert this string to a number, and give it to the network. My confusion is - given that i am unaware of whether there is a relationship between the country bred and the output, and given that I am randomly assigning a number to each country, would this not affect the network negatively if the value assigned to each country does not correspond with the actual performance of the country ?

Comment: If you are unsure about whether there is a relationship or not you should always start out by plotting the data. Looking at a simple plot goes a long way towards telling if the relationship is worth further exploration or not. For the other queston, see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008174/nominal-value-inputs-for-neural-network/9017049#9017049